# Trigger is not Working in PhpMyAdmin sql tab

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I trying to trigger update in my PhpMyAdmin SQL tab but it showing me error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

Here is my Query

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON hodm
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO hodm_log
    SET log_action = 'update',
     user_name = NEW.user_name,
        log_timestamp = NOW();
END
```

I have two table one is hodm and another is hodm_log. I want if any update occurs in the hodm table then it needs to reflect in the hodm_log table.

Please help me to find the answer.

Comment: You cannot use a set statement with an insert - try a values clause instead.

Comment: @P.Salmon I didn't get you please explain

Comment: A quick solution might be to remove `begin` and `end`. Otherwise, you probably have to add a `delimiter`, see e.g. the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html). Or use the trigger-section of phpmysql, it does that stuff for you.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanx for helps me to find the answer.  I post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer Thanx to @Solarflare for helping me to find the answer.

Here is my working code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON hodm
    FOR EACH ROW 

    INSERT INTO hodm_log
    SET log_action = 'update',
     user_name = NEW.user_name,
        log_timestamp = NOW();
```

Thank you